# SpriteKit Particle emitter vrs for loop

Tags: for-loop, sprite-kit

Hello I am working in SpriteKit and I am trying to decide the best method to accomplish something.

I what an effect where when the user "Shoots" and 100 tiny objects "swarm" the "target". In other words I want 100 nodes to run the same SKAction. Now I've thought of two ways to do this and I am wondering if there is a difference and if one is better than the other.

Method A: I have a for loop that creates a tiny object and have it run an action and loops 100 times.

Method B: I have a particle emitter that emits 100 particles and I have those run the action.

Is there a difference between the two? Or boiled down are they really the same thing? And if they're different which is better to use?

Comment: If you can do it with emitter, I guess it would be a performant as well as the easiest solution. If that is not an option, pooling would be a good solution. Search about pooling here or at the Ray's site, its described there in detail...